# ¿Cómo adquirió "a mansalva" su significado actual?

Tags: etimología, expresiones, significado

Os cuento cómo he llegado a plantear esta pregunta, porque el camino seguido me parece interesante. El caso es que no me acuerdo ahora mismo dónde (juraría que fue leyendo el diccionario de Covarrubias, pero no estoy seguro) descubrí que existe una forma apocopada de *mano*:

> **[man](http://dle.rae.es/?id=O78WwZ0)**
>
> <sup><sub>Apóc.</sub></sup>
>
> 1. f. desus. mano.

De esta forma *man* se derivan palabras como *[mandoble](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OA48abl)* (golpe que se da con un arma empuñada a dos manos) o *[mansalva](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OFx8dxD)*. Sin embargo, el significado de la expresión *a mansalva* no me cuadraba con el significado de *salvo, a*. Me fui al diccionario y vi lo siguiente:

> **[mansalva](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OFx8dxD)**
>
> <sup><sub>De *man* y *salva*, f. de *salvo*.</sub></sup>
>
> **a mansalva**
>
> Tb. **a man salva**, desus.
>
> 1. loc. adv. En gran cantidad o abundancia.
> 2. loc. adv. desus. Sin ningún peligro, sobre seguro.

Así me quedó más claro: la acepción original (ahora en desuso) era "sin ningún peligro, sobre seguro", que cuadra más con su etimología "a mano salva". Pero de ahí pasó a significar "en gran cantidad", que es el significado que hoy le damos a la expresión.

¿Cuál es la conexión, si es que la hay, entre ambas acepciones? ¿Cuándo y cómo se originó la acepción actual?

Bonus opcional: ¿qué otras palabras conocéis con una etimología similar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En el Quijote hay un pasaje donde aparece *a mano salva*:

> Queríale responder Sancho, cuando se lo estorbó ver que por aquella
>   campaña venía huyendo una liebre, seguida de muchos galgos y
>   cazadores, la cual, temerosa, se vino a recoger y a agazapar debajo de
>   los pies del rucio. Cogióla Sancho **a mano salva** y presentósela a
>   don Quijote, el cual estaba diciendo (...)

En la nota que acompaña al texto se explica que *a mano salva* significa "simplemente con la mano, con toda facilidad". De manera que ya en este momento la expresión ha mutado de "sin peligro" (implicado por la idea de mantener la mano "a salvo") a "con facilidad".

Por la misma época (comienzos del siglo XVII) se emplea *a mano salva* con un sentido similar, aunque no idéntico (fuente: Fray Prudencio de Sandoval, *Historia de la vida y hechos del Emperador Carlos V*):

> Todo lo que proponen y platican es para meter tiempo en medio, para
>   forzar su parte, desmayar la nuestra, y al fin salir **a mano salva**
>   con su intento, como saldrán, si vuesa excelencia no pone la mano en
>   ello, como la ha de poner.

Aquí parece que *salir a mano salva* sea más bien "salirse con la suya" o "salir bien parados" o una mezcla de las dos cosas.

En un contexto militar ya encontramos lo siguiente, en el mismo texto:

> De los tudescos había mayor número, porque como desde el principio
>   habían andado tan mal, no se hacía cuenta dellos, y como don Manuel de
>   Luna viese las cosas en tal estado, hablando con los capitanes
>   acordaron de rendirse y no esperar que **a mano salva** los degollasen
>   los franceses y saqueasen aquella villa.

Aquí, si bien todavía es razonable pensar que la expresión significa "sin dificultad", el contexto comienza a acercar el significado al que es más habitual hoy en día.

En el siglo XIX los textos recogen la variante *a salva mano*, todavía con el significado aparente de "sin peligro, sin dificultad", pero también en un contexto donde se le une la abundancia:

> Por no gastar lo necesario en artillería y municiones de guerra,
>   nuestras naves mercantes no podían defenderse de los enemigos que las
>   asaltaban y tomaban **a salva mano** con pérdida de la hacienda de los
>   pasajeros.

Otra:

> Que al demagogo que en traidor arcano
>   Celando su venganza y ambición,
>   Hace la corte al pueblo soberano,
>   Sube al poder, y ejerce **a salva mano**
>   Rapiña y proscripción.

Lo que me parece interesante es que en todos los casos citados el significado puede ser tanto uno como el otro. Hoy en día, no obstante, no es común el uso del adjetivo *salvo*, y por tanto no es esperable que se entienda *a mano salva* como "con las manos protegidas de daño", "sin exponer las manos (= sin exponerse físicamente) al peligro". La frase ya se empleaba como una locución inseparable hace siglos y al apocoparse se ha hecho aún menos analizable.

Imagino que lo que ha ocurrido es que la asociación de circunstancias habituales en el contexto donde más se utilizaba la expresión (contexto de lucha, asedio, asalto militar) terminó por desplazar el significado. En un asalto donde unos superan ampliamente a otros, los unos quizá atacan y matan sin dificultad y sin gran peligro a un gran número de los otros. Si *man-* ya no se entiende como *mano* y *-salva* no recuerda a "salvarse, estar protegido, estar fuera de peligro", es muy razonable que quien escucha la narración de un ataque de este tipo concluya que *a mansalva* significa "en gran cantidad".